# How Can you split a multiline textbox into separate lines to be added to a list? C#

Tags: c#, list, split, textbox

Hi there I am having issues trying to get the multiline textbox to go into a list Box.
I'm trying to make each line of the textbox go to a separate **index**(position?) in the list  (the textbox automatically makes a newline when it cant fit any more horizontal words

[Picture Of My GUI to Explain what I'm doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMzpT.png)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: sorry ill just grab some snippits of code for context

Comment: Do try to search the site for existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text has line breaks, you can use

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or you can use this to handle different types of line breaks

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
StringSplitOptions.None);
```